# Where to find script causing mixed content Joomla

Tags: joomla-2.5, ssl

I setup an SSL on my Joomla website. Right after the SSL is enabled, the submenus are not displayed.

I checked the browser options and found Mixed Content. There is a script which is not loading http.

I need to find where this script is located, and where it is being called.

I searched the following path:

```
reliablerenovationsplus/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php
```

but I don't see any scripts or references.

So, I wonder: How can I replace the script loading http with https to avoid the mixed content, to see if that fixes the menu issue.

Check the following screenshot, which shows you the issue I am having:
[image]

Comment: `head.php` is a core Joomla file, so it won't be in there. The jQuery file is most likely coming from an extension. You're best bet is to do a mass search for `googleapis` in your entire Joomla directory to find out where it's coming from exactly.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for joining us in JSE.  Please take our [tour].  Please continue to research, debug, and attempt to self-solve.  If you discover more clues, please edit them into your question body.  If you can resolve your own question, please post an educational answer to benefit others with a similar problem.  P.S. It is certainly time to upgrade out of Joomla2.5.

Comment: @mickmackusaI will do it if I find the answer, thanks thou